# removing layout_width parameter from xml file causes error

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        .......
   </ScrollView>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

This is my xml file.i want to set the **width of fragment in java file**.like this

```
 int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
  DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) drawerFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        drawerFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

But for that I need to remove 
   **android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"** from fragment in xml file.
but when I am removing I am getting compile time error. 
I am working on android studio.
how to fix that problem.can anyone help me.

Comment: width and height attribute required for all type views in xml you can not remove it but yes you can change width and height value from java code at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove width and height attributes from XML it's required.

but you can set it to 0 instead like that: `android:layout_width="0dp"`

I think this the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed with the last comment, height and width are mandatory parameters everytime that you crate a view in your xml file. So, set there a generic value and after, you will modify that value programmatically.

By the way, I am not sure if you can use the "DrawerLayout.LayoutParams" as a parameters to modify the height or width of that fragment. In you case I will use this code that for sure is going to work:

```
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) (getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer));
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mMapFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.width= width;
mMapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Another advice offtopic: I saw in your xml that you are using maybe too much linearlayout. Keep in mind that this is going to be slower your app. You should always try to use the fewer linear and relative nested will be better. By example, I say that container_app_bar layout is containing the app_bar right? and for sure that inside of this app_bar the parent is a linearlayout too...maybe you can remove container_app_bar. I think you don't need it. (It is only one example).

Comment: thanks.the above code works for me.and i need that container_app_bar.i am working on material design.

Comment: ok can u tell me what is the width of the navigation drawer so that it will look good in all type of device means mobile and tablet.
for that width only i wrote

 int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = drawerFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
        params.width= width;
        drawerFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);

it looks good in tablet.bt in mobile device it isn't looking good.

Comment: The value that you ask me is quite relative...depend of how do you want to look it? Look, in my app,only i use for mobile devices and I have set up it to 250dp. Maybe you can set up it with this value by default, and by code, check if the app is running in a tabletdevice, and if it is, modify the width value by code.

Comment: yes the app is running in both mob and tablet.that's why i don't want to do it hardcoded.i want it to be dynamic.

Comment: ask a new question in stackoverflow...maybe someone could help up better than me.